# Is "is possible to achieve" good or not?

Tags: phrases

Is this a grammatical sentence?

> "XXX is possible to achieve."

It feels funny, but it has the same structure as:

> "XXX is difficult to achieve.

I can't tell if the first is grammatical but the second is perfectly normal for me. Especially if I put a subject in:

> Perfection is difficult to achieve.

That sounds good.

> Perfection is possible to achieve.

I can't tell about that one.

Comment: Some notes regarding questions on [proofreading](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10573/142322).

Comment: 'Impossible' certainly undergoes tough movement: 'This problem is impossible to solve.' But [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tough_movement) does not include 'possible' in its list of '[some] adjectives that allow this construction'. I've a horrible feeling that 'NP is possible to achieve' is a lot more idiomatic than 'NP is possible to solve'.

Comment: I estimate from these [GoogleNgrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+is+possible+to+achieve%2Cit+is+possible+to+solve%2Cis+possible+to+achieve%2Cis+possible+to+solve&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20is%20possible%20to%20achieve%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20is%20possible%20to%20solve%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20possible%20to%20achieve%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20possible%20to%20solve%3B%2Cc0) (take off the 'delexical it' false-positives) that 'NP is possible to achieve' is three times as common as 'NP is possible to solve'.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is grammatical, but it is not minimal, and cutting out unnecessary wording is a Good Thing.

"XXX is possible to achieve" really means the same as "XXX is possible," so there's no need for the extra words.

But "XXX is difficult" won't substitute for "XXX is difficult to achieve."  It could be emotionally difficult, that is, stressful.  Example:  "Living with arthritis is difficult sometimes."  That's not about achieving life, just about stress and unpleasantness.

But if context makes it obvious, you can omit "to achieve" without confusion:  "Finding the answer was difficult."